# Can't make a slice of a column of a 2d array "cannot use Sudoku[0:9][0] (type [9]int) as type []int in assignment"

Tags: arrays, go, slice, sudoku

I'm making a simple game of sudoku using slices of a 9x9 2d array. I'm still starting out with Golang and have some C++ experience. I keep getting the error message "cannot use Sudoku[0:9][0] (type [9]int) as type []int in assignment".

var row1 []int = Sudoku[0][0:9]
This line correctly took the values of the first row of the 2d array and placed them into the row1 slice, but using var col1 []int = Sudoku[0:9][0] results in the error message above. What can I do? Thanks in advance!

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var Sudoku [9][9]int
    fmt.Println(Sudoku)
    var row1 []int = Sudoku[0][0:9]
    fmt.Println(row1)
    var col1 []int = Sudoku[0:9][0]
    fmt.Println(col1)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Jk6sqqXR5VE

```
10:6: cannot use Sudoku[0:9][0] (type [9]int) as type []int in assignment
```

Comment: Arrays like [9]int and slices like []int arer different types in Go. Take the Tour of Go.

Comment: took the tour. What I don't understand is what alternative. I want a slice to contain the values of one column of the 2d array. How can I do this considering the above method failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var col1 []int = Sudoku[0:9][0]` gets you an array, not a slice.  You could either declare as `var col1 [9]int = Sudoku[0:9][0]` (or better: `col1 := Sudoku[0:9][0]`), or if you really want a slice: `var col1Slice []int = col1[:]` after getting col1.

In general, things would be much easier if your sudoku structure were a 2D slice instead of 2D array, then you'd be dealing with only slices.

Working example of all of these:
https://play.golang.org/p/LE8qwFSy1m_e

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: In Go, array and slice are not exactly the same. You can't assign a slice variable to an array value.

Details:

1. We start with `Sudoku [9][9]int` variable is an array.
2. The valid line `var row1 []int = Sudoku[0][0:9]`:
3. `Sudoku[0]` returns the element at index 0 of `Sudoku`, which is an array `[9]int`. Let's say we call this temporary result `temp`
4. Then `temp[0:9]`returns a slice of elements between index 0 and 9 (exclusive) in `temp`. That's why you can assign that to a slice variable `row1`
5. Now the trouble line `var col1 []int = Sudoku[0:9][0]`. Based on the naming, I guess your intention is to return the first column from `Sudoku` array
   ? Unfortunately, this is what happens:
6. `Sudoku[0:9]` returns the slice of elements between index 0 and 9 (exclusive) of `Sudoku`. Because each element in `Sudoku` is an array, this `temp` value actually holds all the rows from `Sudoku` and of type `[][9]int`.
7. Now `temp[0]`returns the first element of `temp`, which actually is just the first row of `Sudoku` and of type array `[9]int`. Thus, Go will complain when you try to assign it to a variable of type `[]int` (a slice)

So if Sudoku is a matrix of

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
...
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
```

Even if Go does not complain about typing, the returned value will be `[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]` and not `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]`